# Cannot disable module on Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, logging, module

I used command apachectl -M , I disabled all unecessary mods and now I am trying to disable logs for apache I get :

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

I used

```
 a2dismod log_config, a2dismod log, a2dismod log_config_module, a2dismod mod_log_config , a2dismod mod_log
```

and I always get

```
 ERROR: Module log_config does not exist!
```

I cannot update Apache and also I am a sudoer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log_config_module is static module. If the module is static, that means it is compiled in. There is no easy way to add/remove them without recompiling.